# Status of the Leopoldt conjecture ? 

Tags: nt.number-theory, big-picture

In 2009 Mihailescu published a proof of the famous Leopoldt conjecture on the arxiv. Later on, in 2011, he  published a 'lightweight' version that proves the conjecture for CM fields. Also compare

[Is the Leopoldt conjecture almost always true?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66252/is-the-leopoldt-conjecture-almost-always-true/69118#69118)

But as far as I can see from MathSciNet, none of his papers has been 
published in any math journal. So here are my questions:

1. Has anybody information if Mihailescu intends to get his proof printed in some math journal or if it's destined solely to the arxiv (like Perelman has done) ?
2. In his [obituary for Leopoldt](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~ci3/manu.html#LEOPOLDT) from 10.01.2012, Roquette mentions in a footnote, "recently Mihailescu has announced a proof of Leopoldt's conjecture for all number fields". Is this a new announcement or  refers Roquette to Mihailescu's 2009 paper ?
3. What's the current status of the Leopoldt conjecture ?

Comment: In view of the answer to the question linked to I vote to close this. Alos, there seems to be no clear motivation for this question beyond general interest.  

Comment: @quid: It may be of interest to someone who wants to attack Leopoldt conjecture himself. To the OP: regarding 1., have you tried emailing Mihailescu?

Comment: @quid: I think it's of general interest to know about the status (that may change over time) of important conjectures in a field. That's why I used the big picture tag. @Kevin: No, I thought I ask at first on MO before contacting him. 

Comment: I went to considerable lengths to argue for some question like this to *stay open* on *other* occassions; this one seems purely gossip-y and we *know* that the author is not keen on this discussion to happen on MO. Also, 1. IMO is an inapropriate question to ask. 2. should be best asked to Roquette (though I guess if he did not add details he meant the one everybody knows about), and for 3. well most likely as a coupele of month ago. 

Comment: I think that a question on the status of Leopoldt's conjecture might be appropriate and even interesting if carefully formulated. However, I agree with quid that question 1 is extremely inappropriate: submission and rejection should not be public, only acceptance should. 

Comment: Of course you are both right. I was thinking more about whether he intended on submitting a paper, but I suppose this is a sensitive question if the answer is yes.

Comment: I think if someone publishes a paper in the internet, saying I'm the one who proved this important conjecture, then it's no longer his private affair. He then has to reckon that people start asking about the work's approval status. Moreover if an important proof is sent to a journal with high reputation then it should be possible to decide within 3 years if it's correct or if there are gaps. Hence the unclear status of Mihailescu's work is unsatisfying. But I agree that it's up to him to give information about the approval status - that shouldn't be done by /asked to third parties. 

Comment: @KBuck: we (you and I) do not have any fundamental/general disagreement on this. I think I agree with Olivier that a carefully formulated question along these lines could be good. However, I do not find this question carefully formulated; in particular, there is little to nothing that documents a detailed mathematical interest in the matter (maybe it is there, but it is not visible from the question). You could start a meta-thread (extra sign-up necessary, but simple and instant) to further discuss this or to work on an improved version.  

Comment: Like quid, I encourage you to ask a reworded question. I'd be glad to do my best to answer it.